# Using html and html5 together

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there a reason Stack Overflow allows you to use both the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag and [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5)? The [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) seems kind of redundant in this case.

Secondary question: Is there a reason we still have a separate HTML and HTML5 tag? Most of the HTML5 elements are supported by every major browser (with [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) being the lowest supporting more than 350 out of ~550 elements).

Answer (score 8):

`html` is for HTML questions in general; `html5` for questions specific to version 5.

- Having both around makes sense because not every HTML question is specific to the unique features and behaviours provided by HTML 5
- Using both in a question makes sense in order for questions specific to something about HTML 5 to reach the right people (i.e. those who have subscribed to the `html` tag but maybe not `html5`).

Comment: Honestly don't know who downvoted this, this is perfectly accurate

Comment: @Gjhuizing On meta, downvotes indicate disagreement. Perhaps someone thought that subscribing to `html` but not `html5` was nonsensical. That's just their opinion.

Comment: That's what I meant ;)